# chrome for mobile ignores height 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have this html: http://jsfiddle.net/nsabu/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
    html, body, img {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.storage.mediabox.io/1/_content/664536771c9060e8459805d4ed7103fa-40/198-40_100_2.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAJNMOEPRUOJXCJJ5Q&Expires=1356669400&Signature=Su6bomRoQ8FT6yllzIzPGGyaqWU%3D&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzENr%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEa0AFP2Myc69na3yO7inJ7d9KqZwS620cUDmdLiSIQmtR3wrgxetmy1N3JNCVAdz1mOTqqwKiKpPXY5dVf0OxTBY%2BLUoAovSz9OjUojB0JQlXqMVeNbAzhq723O32OZR08l6F2S0oyIOgwjr%2FGkzj2JhNunzfido49SdTjEiX2p5WozIVODRqnxkqrXrDL4z1vMunQkivQ8U2VKlL4s8z3mEwd3tvWUaOu0%2B%2BUFvHiGH23V05pXQEnZnlLKQ%2B6NNwmmp2Rt5EsmMvvTJi4CYbjM6cJIJjP7IYF" />
</body>
</html>
```

When I run it on chrome I get 100% height for the image. When I ran it on tablet or mobile phone with chrome, the browser ignores the 100% height. What is the problem? How can I tell the chrome mobile browser consider the height?

Comment: out of curiosity what height do you get?

Comment: is it something to do with a missing viewport setting?

Comment: @eds: I get the original size of the image.

Comment: @popnoodles: I didn't add viewport as you can see. Is something like this missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the viewport tag

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1"/>
    <style>
    html, body, img {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/dev.storage.mediabox.io/1/_content/664536771c9060e8459805d4ed7103fa-40/198-40_100_2.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAJNMOEPRUOJXCJJ5Q&Expires=1356669400&Signature=Su6bomRoQ8FT6yllzIzPGGyaqWU%3D&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzENr%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEa0AFP2Myc69na3yO7inJ7d9KqZwS620cUDmdLiSIQmtR3wrgxetmy1N3JNCVAdz1mOTqqwKiKpPXY5dVf0OxTBY%2BLUoAovSz9OjUojB0JQlXqMVeNbAzhq723O32OZR08l6F2S0oyIOgwjr%2FGkzj2JhNunzfido49SdTjEiX2p5WozIVODRqnxkqrXrDL4z1vMunQkivQ8U2VKlL4s8z3mEwd3tvWUaOu0%2B%2BUFvHiGH23V05pXQEnZnlLKQ%2B6NNwmmp2Rt5EsmMvvTJi4CYbjM6cJIJjP7IYF" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not working.. The image still don't have 100% height on mobile device with chrome. If you have an android device with chrome you can check it and see.

Comment: aw. it does on my Android tablet using Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Try `height: 100vh;` instead (CSS3, supported in all browsers). It may solve your troubles.
For further informaiton see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667